# PHP Division return Floating Point that contains E issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to do division in my code, here is mine:

```
$total = $dateRange / $value; // 2 / 10000000
```

it give me result **2.0E-7** instead of 0.0000002. Isn't it a floating point?
I've tried to use *convert to string* or *json_decode* it's still give me same result, and `number_format((float) $result, 6, '.', '')` gives me 
**0.000000**

Comment: `number_format($result, 7, '.', '')`.

Comment: `number_format($foo, 7)` works well.

Comment: Do you realize that 2.0E-7 is exactly 0.0000002?

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
echo rtrim(rtrim(sprintf('%.8F', $result), '0'), ".");
```